# How do I fix a blank white screen for Visual Studio Code run remotely through X11?

Tags: visual-studio-code, x11, ubuntu-20.04

Visual Studio Code displays perfectly from a local display on a Ubuntu 20 installation, but just produces a blank white window when run from a remote Ubuntu machine through X-windows.  Running `code --disable-gpu` doesn't help.  Other applications such as Firefox, Nautilus, and Eclipse display remotely with no problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue for this upstream: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110119

Running `code --verbose --log debug --disable-gpu` prints, among others:

```
[3440:1116/110926.098706:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1520)] X error received: serial 169, error_code 1 (BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)), request_code 130, minor_code 1 (X_ShmAttach)
[3440:1116/110926.129228:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1520)] X error received: serial 170, error_code 1 (BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)), request_code 130, minor_code 1 (X_ShmAttach)
[3440:1116/110926.170878:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1520)] X error received: serial 171, error_code 1 (BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)), request_code 130, minor_code 3 (X_ShmPutImage)
[3440:1116/110926.204224:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1520)] X error received: serial 172, error_code 1 (BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)), request_code 130, minor_code 3 (X_ShmPutImage)
```

I don't know much about X, but I would expect X shared memory (shm) to not work via X forwarding, and maybe it's something that vscode currently needs?

Comment: I had the same problem with my local machine. I ran this command once, and the issue was fixed. Even when I run `code` with no args.

Answer (score 1):

For me the "--disable-extensions --disable-gpu" options worked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it started in rev 1.66 on my Linux systems.

I uninstalled and installed 1.65 from here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_65

Answer (score 0):

Just install an old version of VS Code.

I use version 1.59.1 and I don't have a white screen anymore when I use sudo.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade from 1.82v to 1.65v did the trick!